# How to count spring coil turns?

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, image-segmentation

In reference to: [How to detect and count a spiral's turns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563880/c-sharp-wpf-emgu-how-to-detect-and-count-a-spirals-turns)

I am not able to get count even in the pixel based calculation also.

If I have attached image how to start with the counting the turns.

I tried the FindContours(); but doesn't quite get the turns segregated which it can't. Also the matchshape() I have the similarity factor but for whole coil.

So I tried as follows for turn count:

```
 public static int GetSpringTurnCount()
        {
            if (null == m_imageROIed)
                return -1;
            int imageWidth = m_imageROIed.Width;
            int imageHeight = m_imageROIed.Height;

            if ((imageWidth <= 0) || (imageHeight <= 0))
                return 0;

            int turnCount = 0;

            Image<Gray, float> imgGrayF = new Image<Gray, float>(imageWidth, imageHeight);

            CvInvoke.cvConvert(m_imageROIed, imgGrayF);

            imgGrayF = imgGrayF.Laplace(1); // For saving integer overflow.

            Image<Gray, byte> imgGray = new Image<Gray, byte>(imageWidth, imageHeight);
            Image<Gray, byte> cannyEdges = new Image<Gray, byte>(imageWidth, imageHeight);

            CvInvoke.cvConvert(imgGrayF, imgGray);

            cannyEdges = imgGray.Copy();

            //cannyEdges = cannyEdges.ThresholdBinary(new Gray(1), new Gray(255));// = cannyEdges > 0 ? 1 : 0;
            cannyEdges = cannyEdges.Max(0);

            cannyEdges /= 255;

            Double[] sumRow = new Double[cannyEdges.Cols];
            //int sumRowIndex = 0;
            int Rows = cannyEdges.Rows;
            int Cols = cannyEdges.Cols;
            for (int X = 0; X < cannyEdges.Cols; X++)
            {
                Double sumB = 0;

                for (int Y = 0; Y < cannyEdges.Rows; Y ++)
                {
                    //LineSegment2D lines1 = new LineSegment2D(new System.Drawing.Point(X, 0), new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y));

                    Double pixels = cannyEdges[Y, X].Intensity;

                    sumB += pixels;


                }
                sumRow[X] = sumB;
            }

            Double avg = sumRow.Average();

List<int> turnCountList = new List<int>();

            int cnt = 0;
            foreach(int i in sumRow)
            {
                sumRow[cnt] /=  avg;
                if(sumRow[cnt]>3.0)
                turnCountList.Add((int)sumRow[cnt]);
                    cnt++;
            }
            turnCount = turnCountList.Count();

 cntSmooth = cntSmooth * 0.9f + (turnCount) * 0.1f;
            return (int)cntSmooth;
    }
```

[image]

I am next trying surf.

==================================================

Edit: Adding samples. If you like it do it.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

==================================================

Edit: Tried another algo:

1. ROI then Rotate ( biggest thin light blue rectangle )
2. GetMoments() shrink ROI height and position.Y using the moment.
3. Set the shrinked ROI and ._And() it with a blank image. ( Gray region with green rectangle )
4. cut the image into half-half.
5. contour and fit ellipse.
6. get maximum number of fitted ellipses.

Later will work on better algos and results.

[image]

Comment: In general, your questions are difficult to understand.  Consider getting someone adept at English to proofread your questions for clarity and legibility.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the bigger cluster of white colour is the spring

--EDIT--

1. Apply inverse threshold to the picture and fill corners with flood fill algorithm.
2. Find the rotated bounding box of the biggest white cluster using findContours and minAreaRect
3. Trace the box longer axis doing the following
4. for each pixel along the axis trace axis line perpendicular going through current pixel
5. This line will cross the spring in minimum two points.
6. Find the point with the bigger distane from the axis
7. This will create collection on points similar to sine function
8. Count the peaks or clusters of this collection this will get twice the number of loops.

All this assuming you don't have high noise in the picture.

Comment: dear @Michael Kupchick: I think I already have covered up all the steps but 4. How wud I go about step 4? I think averaging division in my algorithm somehow does that. What do u say?

Comment: Yes in fact I didn't notice that you run Laplacian on the image. I will see at your code again and post what I found.

Comment: Wud be thankful to you :). I'll put some variety of images. Just choose on anyone.

Comment: I don't have time today to complete the code. But basically my idea is similar to what you are doing in the update. In fact in order to count the loops we need to count the peaks on the bottom or the top.

Comment: Dear @Michael Kupchick, please don't put time on writing code for it. The way you write the algorithm, point wise. Helps a lot. Thanks. Wud be able to appreciate more if u wud extend ur answer in that way. :)

Comment: I need to work on mean-shift. Seems nice for my use. But m not able to use it. I will inform.

Comment: Edited my answer with better sequence

Comment: Thanks. Will start on it on Monday. Or may be today eve. Please wait for my response.

Comment: It will be nice for quick evaluation. Please add it in ur answer. And also mention which images u've tried it on. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, m going through the algo. Point 4 is where I am not able to go through. Instead of going entirely pixel by pixel I tried cvDistanceTransform, which gives image by which the pixel wise RowSum() gives me a logical weight by which I can get the peaks. But not working. How to go about step 4 strictly if my way is wrong. Sorry for iterative questions and thanks in advance.