# How to segment a part of any object for counting purpose as per given binary image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

**Objective:** I want to count [image] from image below.

[image]

What are the ideas can work here?

I tried `FindContour()`. It returns boundary. Further I need to use those contour points.Using matchShape() and Contour.slice() is not helping.. Any working example for this case will be very helpful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, perform a normalized cross correlation and find relevant peaks. To improve your results, you need to rethink/redo the earlier steps that got to this image your are showing. You need to consider whether you actually did the best/correct steps to get to it.

Here is the normalized cross relation result cropped to the original size, and the non-black points for where the result is greater than 0.35 (the implementation I used produces values in the range [-1, 1]).

[image] [image]

The right image is trivially binarized, and gives 5 components, which is your result.

Comment: I have shine contours but I don't want to rely on shine. Because the object is varying in size and sometimes can't even make shine spots. I have tried several things. This is my 4th algorithm, to strongly go forward with. You can go through the link [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820556/how-to-count-spring-coil-turns/13846075 ]. I had to repeat it. I am now trying "normalized cross correlation". Right now I don't even know what it is.

Comment: k I think I got it: CvInvoke.cvMatchTemplate(cvImage.Ptr, cvTemplate.Ptr, similarityMap.Ptr, TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);

Comment: Awsm it works.... Thanks a lot. This is a generalized one. Solves the purpose. However looking for more ideas. Thanks again. After a long time I could mark reply as correct answer.

Comment: I saw another question of yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563880/how-to-detect-and-count-a-spirals-turns. There I proposed something different that might work, but the height of the line structuring element needs to be adapted to the different regions.